# if --help doesn't work in terminal

Tags: bash, shell

```
if --help
```

doesn't work in terminal, why?

Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon 64bit

Shell: Bash

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you specify what environment (OS version, shell type and version, ...) you use and where you have actually seen it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See : `help --help` or `help`

> ```
> Display information about builtin commands.
> ```

`help if`:

```
if: if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; ]... [ else COMMANDS; ] fi
    Execute commands based on conditional.

    The `if COMMANDS' list is executed.  If its exit status is zero, then the
    `then COMMANDS' list is executed.  Otherwise, each `elif COMMANDS' list is
    executed in turn, and if its exit status is zero, the corresponding
    `then COMMANDS' list is executed and the if command completes.  Otherwise,
    the `else COMMANDS' list is executed, if present.  The exit status of the
    entire construct is the exit status of the last command executed, or zero
    if no condition tested true.

    Exit Status:
    Returns the status of the last command executed.
```

Comment: The help for the if command is too poor in information. Thanks anyway, it's the solution to the question.

Comment: @RiccardoLaMarca because it isn't a command. You need to read `man bash` for more details, or look at shell scripting guides. `if` isn't a command, it's a programming construct.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure where you may have seen this work, but `if` is a keyword of the shell and used for test constructs; it is not a command and hence cannot be called with the usual `--help` option. Instead, it will block and wait for further input (i.e. a test statement) until you press `Ctrl-C` to forcefully quit the started command.

If you need help on how to use the `if` keyword in shell scripts, the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html) or Lhunath & GreyCat's [Bash Guide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) might be a good starting point.